# Is there any problem with this code? I'm new on html & css

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure this code is written in the shortest and most effective way. Please help me.. How can i write in the shortest way? And how can I improve myself?

```
* {margin: 0;padding: 0;box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
background: #fff;
font-family: Arial;
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #333;
}

nav {background-color: #f7f7f7;
width: 100%;
display: block;
}

nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
}

nav ul:not(.sub-menu) > li {
padding: 15px;
}

nav ul:not(.sub-menu) > li + li {
margin-left: 20px;
}

nav ul li.has-children:hover ul.sub-menu {display: block;
}

nav ul.sub-menu {
position: absolute;
display: none;
white-space: nowrap;
/* Her bir liste öğesinin tek bir satır olması için. */
top: 100%;
}

nav ul.sub-menu li {
display: block;
}

nav ul.sub-menu li a {
display: block;
padding: 12px 20px 12px 10px;
background-color: #f7f7f7;
border-with: 0 1px 1px 1px;
border-color: #eee;
border-style: solid;
}

nav ul.sub-menu li a:hover {background-color: #eee;}

nav ul.sub-menu li + li a {
border-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the code itself is pretty short. You can take care of a few points which will help you in the long run.

1. Try to minimise the use of `>` and `+`. As these are strictly bound to the structure of the DOM. If the DOM changes, styles with `>` or `+` might break.
2. Minimise the hierarchy. `nav ul li` can be replaced with `nav li`. Lesser the hierarchy, faster will be the DOM painting.
3. Something more you should do is separate the css in 2 parts.

   - Part 1: All element level css (lets call it normalize.css) and
   - Part 2: All class based css(lets call it styles.css).

**Normalize.css** now has the global styles for the html elements, which is common throughout your web page.

```
* {margin: 0;padding: 0;box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: Arial;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

nav {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav li { // note that the `ul` is removed
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

**style.css** now containes all class based css which is independent of its position in the DOM.

```
.menu-item { // add a class `menu-item` to the immediate UL items in the <nav/>
  padding: 15px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.menu-item:first-child {// remove margin-left from the first-child
  margin-left: 0;
}

.menu-item:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}

.sub-menu { // removing the unnecessary qualifiers. `.sub-menu` is enough
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  top: 100%;
}

.sub-menu-item { // add class `sub-menu-item` to the <li> of `.sub-menu`
  display: block;
}

.sub-menu-item a { // you can further go ahead to add a special class to the `<a/>` inside `.sub-menu-item`
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 10px;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border-with: 0 1px 1px 1px;
  border-color: #eee;
  border-style: solid;
}

.sub-menu-item a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}

nav ul.sub-menu li + li a { // similarly you can remove the `+` with `:first-child` or the suitable.
  border-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. How I seperate css files?

css/style.css
css/normalize.css

is that true?

Comment: mostly what we do is , have 1 index.css, which is included in you html file. In your index.css, try importing `normalize.css` and `style.css` by `@import`. Something like this: `@import url("css/normalize.css");`

Answer (score 1):

Your css is accurate which is a good point. But if you want to make your life easier and not repeat yourself, I advise you to use a css preprocessor like [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/) to write css like this :

```css
nav {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;

        li {
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
        }
    }
}
```